# Spring security - Custom ExceptionTranslationFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

This question is actually related to this issue [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063342/spring-security-with-restcontroller-jsonish-customauthenticationprovider-resp/37063583#37063583).

Based on the suggestion from @harsh-poddar, I added the filter accordingly.

However, after adding that it seems like I can't login even with valid credential.

**Following is the related code:**

*SecurityConfig*

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//  @Bean
//  public CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
//      return new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint();
//  }

@Bean
public CustomExceptionTranslationFilter customExceptionTranslationFilter() {
    return new CustomExceptionTranslationFilter(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        //Note : Able to login without this filter, but after adding this, valid credential also fails
        .addFilterAfter(customExceptionTranslationFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class)
//      .exceptionHandling()
//          .authenticationEntryPoint(new customAuthenticationEntryPoint())
//          .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .requestCache()
            .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable();
}

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider());
    }
}
```

*CustomAuthenticationProvider*

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

public CustomAuthenticationProvider() {
    super();
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException  {
    final String name = authentication.getName();
    final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    if (name.equals("admin") && password.equals("password")) {
        final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        final UserDetails principal = new User(name, password, grantedAuths);
        final Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password, grantedAuths);
        return auth;
    } else {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("NOT_AUTHORIZED");
    }
}

    @Override
    public boolean supports(final Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

*CustomExceptionTranslationFilter*

```
@Component
public class CustomExceptionTranslationFilter extends ExceptionTranslationFilter {

    public CustomExceptionTranslationFilter(AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
        super(authenticationEntryPoint);
    }
}
```

*CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint*

```
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized.");
    }
}
```

> p/s : sorry for the basic question, I'm really new in spring & spring security.

Comment: See my answer in previos question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063342/spring-security-with-restcontroller-jsonish-customauthenticationprovider-resp/37063583#37063583

Comment: @D0dger : thank you for the answer given. But still the same error remains. Login with valid credential also trigger "AuthExceptionEntryPoint". Any hint where can I check to debug this?

Comment: Turn on logging for `org.springframework.security` package and attach it to question (when valid credentials not working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intended design for `AuthenticationEntryPoint` is to start/initiate an authentication. However, your implementation `CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint` does not do this. Instead, it simply sends back an unauthorized response. Please see javadoc for [AuthenticationEntryPoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html) for more details on implementation specifics.

Based on your configuration you are using HTTP Basic for authentication:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

This specific configuration will automatically configure `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` which is an implementation of `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. The `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` will challenge the user with a http response header of `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="User Realm"` to authenticate, as per [server protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Server_side).

However, the fact that you are configuring your own `CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint` it will ultimately override the `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` which is not what you want to do.

The [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37132751/6105379) recommended this configuration which again is not what you want to do.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint());
}
```

If your main goal is to provide a custom response to the user when authentication fails than I would propose a form login configuration with a configured `AuthenticationFailureHandler`. Here is the configuration:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin().failureHandler(new DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler())
        .and()
    .csrf().disable();   // NOTE: I would recommend enabling CSRF
```

Your implementation of `DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler` would be:

```
public class DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Set status only OR do whatever you want to the response
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

The [AuthenticationFailureHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html) is specifically designed to handle a failed authentication attempt.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've tried this and found that, every request been redirected (302) to "/login". For your info, this is a web service communicate via @RestController.